# JavaFX: is it possible to set a background color for an entire TreeView?

Tags: java, css, javafx, treeview

I have tried the following with no success:

```
.tree-view {
    -fx-skin: "com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.TreeViewSkin";
    -fx-background-color: green, -fx-control-inner-background;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to set a blue background for an entire `TreeView` except the selected one. Setting the background on the selected tree item works fine, but changing for the entire tree view does not have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can color the individual `TreeCell`s by using the `.tree-cell` selector:

```
.tree-view {
    -fx-background-color:lightsteelblue;
}

.tree-cell {
    -fx-background-color:lightsteelblue; // Default color
}

.tree-view:focused .tree-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color:indigo; // Focused color
}

.tree-cell:filled:selected{
    -fx-background-color:lightcyan; // Unfocused color
}
```

Produces something like this:

[image]